# Store matrices and compare them in java

Tags: java

I need to store many matrices and then to compare some of them by retrieving the last matrix added and the previous one.

I create these matrices using:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];
```

My matrices have only 0s, 1s and 2s. I want to compare matrices based on the value of each position. In my case, two matrices are different as long as at least one position has a different value. 
Each matrix is created bases on elements detected via Reactivision. Elements that are not moved are 2s, elements which are added are 1s, and where there isn't anything it's a 0.

For example:

```
1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

would be different.

The number of matrices stored is not fixed. If I have 10 matrix already created, what is the most efficient way to store these and to be able to compare them ?

I've searched for this on StackOverFlow and other forums but can't find any answer

Comment: Why down voting this ? How is it a bad question ? I've looked for it and couldn't find an answer. I could add the code of my sketch but it wouldn't be relevant for the question.

Comment: How do you want to compare matrices? On what basis? While I am not the downvoter, I agree with the one who downvoted if it's on the grounds of this question lacking details. You don't even start to explain the problem at hand.

Comment: @fge thanks I've edited it

Comment: How are you storing your matrices?  If you have a dedicated class, you'll just need to implement `equals` (and `hashCode`).

Comment: That's my question ... how can I store matrices ? They are generated based on elements detected via Reactivision but I don't know how to store them

Comment: That should be specified in the question as well (the Reactivision interaction).

Comment: My question is named "store matrices". What might not be clear is that I already have created the matrices. I now how to create them using
int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since many (maybe most) entries in your matrices are zeroes, it is inefficient to store them *as is*. You need to use a sparse matrix representation. [Here is a pretty exhaustive list of matrix libraries](https://java-matrix.org/), many of which allow for sparse representations.

Most of them will also already have an `equals()` method, which you can override to suit your definition (or not, if their definition is already the same as yours).

Finally, since you need to compare only the last two matrices, you need some sort of a queue. I would maintain a list, and use a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for this.

Comment: But the position of 0s, 1s and 2s matter so will a sparse matrix be a good fit ?

Comment: A sparse matrix is just a more efficient data structure. Mathematically, the sparse and non-sparse representations of a given matrix are equivalent. A sparse representation typically only stores the non-zero values, along with their positions (i.e., the (i,j) indices in the matrix). So yes, the positions will be preserved and accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any code, I can only help you with design.
So, Here is some design tips for you:

1. Store your matrices in two-dimensional arrays

   Ex: `int[][] matrix = new int[5][3];` this gives you a 5x3 matrix.
2. Since you don't know how many matrices you will have, add them into an arraylist.

   Ex: `ArrayList<int[][]> matrices = new ArrayList<>();`
3. I don't know what you mean with comparison but, you can do it using a nested for loop by retrieving the matrices from the arraylist one by one to compare.

Comment: The matrices I've created are based on two dimensional arrays, so my problem would be to store 2 dimensional arrays I guess

Comment: Will I be able to compare them using nested for loops ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to compare them using arraylist. Here's a good ArrayList tutorial for you:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Comment: Storing matrices as 2D arrays is extremely space-inefficient for the type of matrices posted by OP. For a 10x10 matrix with one 1, and all other elements 0, you would need to store 100 elements. A sparse representation, on the other hand, will store only the non-zero indices and values. This comment is based on the `most efficient way to store these` part in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a different class `Matrix` and would override `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

You may want to use sparse matrix representation if most of the values in your matrix would be zero.